# iOS app approval and ATS

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, app-transport-security

I am submitting an app for review. However, my app makes request over normal HTTP (non-ssl) connection. I heard that an app using non-ssl connection will be rejected.

The reason I still have non-ssl connection is because most of the static recourses (images) are distributed by the private cdn over plain http, and there is no plan to upgrade soon.

Is this a valid concern or is Apple simply encouraging developers to use https and the news I heard is exaggerated?

Comment: Why not submit the app and find out? Then _you_ can tell _us_ what happens. Meanwhile, this is really a question about the future — and about what _Apple_ will do in the future — which is kind of useless.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple's review policies.

Comment: It won't make any problem. A couple apps of mine got approved a day ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple reviews all apps based on their app review guidelines which can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). It says nothing about HTTP or HTTPS connections.

In fact, I have several apps using HTTP connections on the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

I've had two different iOS 9 apps approved that use NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key for NSAppTransportSecurity. I think it is *strongly* encouraged but not required (yet).

To bypass ATS:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
```

Comment: Ahh, I remember they required that key when I updated the app to Xcode 7!